# threading in tkinter safely with beatufulsoup

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, beautifulsoup, thread-safety

I've been searching the web but I cant seem to find how to thread tkinter safely.

My aim:

- I'm getting live details of stock prices for the first 25 major
  companies and displaying it in a tkinter scrollable frame.

What I'm trying to do to fix this:

- To try stop lag, I allowed the update to commence every 5 seconds,
  but unfortunately my code still freezes. When I scroll the frame, the
  window gets a heart-attack.
- I read that I should have a separate thread for handling data and
  send this data to the main gui but I cant figure out how to do this
  at the moment

Here's my code:

```
class SecondPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.LiveCanvas = Canvas(self, height=600, bg='#252A2E', highlightthickness=0)
        self.LiveFrame = tk.Frame(self.LiveCanvas)
        self.LiveFrame.configure(bg='#252527')
        self.LiveFrame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.LiveFrame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.LiveCanvas.bind("<Configure>", self.onCanvasConfigure)
        self.LiveCanvas.place(anchor=tk.NE,relx=0.48,y=200,relwidth=0.45)
        self.LiveCanvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.LiveFrame,tags='self.LiveFrame')
        self.Scrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.LiveCanvas.yview)  
        self.Scrollbar.place(in_=self.LiveCanvas,relx=1,x=25,y=0,relheight=1,anchor=tk.NE)

        for count in range(25):
            StockRow = Canvas(self.LiveFrame, height=58, bg='#252527')


    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.LiveCanvas.configure(scrollregion=self.LiveCanvas.bbox("all"))

    def onCanvasConfigure(self, event):
        # width is tweaked to account for window borders
        width = event.width
        self.LiveCanvas.itemconfigure("self.LiveFrame", width=width)


class Live():
    def __init__(self,SecondPage,LiveFrame,LiveCanvas):
        self.LiveFrame = LiveFrame
        self.LiveCanvas = LiveCanvas
        self.UpdateLabel = Label(SecondPage,text='Last Update '+ strftime('%H:%M:%S')).place(x=100,y=100)

        threading._start_new_thread(self.update, ())


    def update(self):
        while True:

            LiveStocksUrl = "https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/most-active"
            LiveStocksUrlOpened = urlopen(LiveStocksUrl)
            HtmlPage = LiveStocksUrlOpened.read()
            LiveStocksUrlOpened.close()

            HttmlPageSoup = BeautifulSoup(HtmlPage, 'html.parser')
            LiveStocksRows = HttmlPageSoup.find_all("tr", class_="simpTblRow")



            co = -1

            count = -1
            for tr in LiveStocksRows:
                count = count + 1

                StockData = tr.find_all('td')
                StockDataRow = ([i.text for i in StockData])

                Symbol, CompanyName, Price, Change, PercentageChange, Volume, AverageVolume, MarketCap, PE = [StockDataRow[index] for index in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)]

                for child in self.LiveFrame.winfo_children():
                    co = co + 1
                    if count == co:
                        for t in child.winfo_children():
                            if t.winfo_class() == "Label":
                                t.place_forget()
                            hi = self.LiveFrame.winfo_children()
                            SymbolLabel = Label(child, text=Symbol, bg='#252527', fg='#EFEFEF').place(x=25,y=17)
                            NameLabel = Label(child, text=CompanyName, bg='#252527', fg='#EFEFEF').place(x=100,y=17)
                            PriceLabel = Label(child, text=Price, bg='#252527', fg='#EFEFEF').place(x=320,y=17)
                            ChangeLabel = Label(child, text=Change + '(' + PercentageChange + ')', bg='#252527', fg='#EFEFEF').place(x=380,y=17)
                            MarketCapLabel = Label(child, text=MarketCap, bg='#252527', fg='#EFEFEF').place(x=500,y=17)
                    else:
                        pass
                co = -1
            self.UpdateLabel.configure(text='Last Update '+ strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
            time.sleep(5)
```

If you need me to edit the code with all the imports and the rest of the code, I am happy to do so, I just wanted to make sure it was easy to read and straight to the point.

Comment: most GUIs don't like to use widgets in threads. In thread you can get data but you may have to use `queue` to send it to main thread which should use `root.after()` to check periodically if there are new data in `queue` and update widget in main thread.

Comment: could you show me how to implement this ?

Comment: if you do `SymbolLabel = Label().place()` then you assign `None` to `SymbolLabel` because `place()`/`grid()`/`pack()` return `None`. If you don't need `SymbolLabel` later then you can simply skip it - `Label().place()` - but if you will need `SymbolLabel` later then you have to do it in two steps - `SymbolLabel = Label()` and `SymbolLabel.pack()`. But maybe you should create labels only once - at start and later only replace text in labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most GUIs don't like to use widgets in threads. In thread you can get data but you may have to use `queue` to send it to main thread which should use `root.after()` to check periodically if there are new data in `queue` and update `widgets` in main thread

---

Minimal working code with `queue` and `after()` to get data from thread and update widgets.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import queue
import time
import random

# --- functions ---

def get_data_from_webpage(q):
    while True:
        
        # get data from webpage
        data = [random.randint(-10,10) for _ in range(20)]
        
        # put in queue
        q.put(data)
        
        time.sleep(0.5)
        
def update_gui():
    # check if new data in queue
    if not q.empty():
        
        # get data from queue
        data = q.get()
        
        # update widgets
        for value, label in zip(data, all_labels):
            label['text'] = value
            if value > 0:
                label['bg'] = 'green'
            elif value < 0:        
                label['bg'] = 'red'
            else:
                label['bg'] = 'grey'

    # run `update_gui` again after 100ms
    root.after(100, update_gui)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

all_labels = []
for item in range(20):
    label = tk.Label(root, width=20)
    label.pack()
    all_labels.append(label)

b = tk.Button(root, text='QUIT', command=root.destroy)
b.pack()

#---
        
# queue to send data between threads    
q = queue.Queue()

# run thread and send queue as argument        
t = threading.Thread(target=get_data_from_webpage, args=(q,))
t.start()

# run `update_gui` first time 
#root.after(100, update_gui)
update_gui()

#---

root.mainloop()

t.join()
```

Comment: hi furas, why is t.join needed at the end? and if i want to make a new thread should i join it also?

Comment: `join()` is used to wait for end of thread. It is useful when thread has to do something else before end of program (i.e. write data in file, free memory, delete temporary files, etc.). WIthout `join()` it may kill thread before it ends its jobs. Frankly, in this example I don't need `join()`. And `join()` would need `while running` instead of `while True` to set `running = False` before `join()` to stop loop. If you use other thread then you should keep threads in separated variables - i.e `t1`, `t2` or on list - and at the end do `t1.join()` `t2.join()`